# Convert string to decimal ignore point

Tags: c#, decimal, dataformat

today iv notice that all the place that im using decimal first thing is in the grid show comma instead of point
the second problame is when i edit or insert number with point it ignore the point

like i enterd "2.5" i got it as 25

thats like example code:

```
decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal("2.5");
```

the resoult of a is 25.

this problame is happening on the iis and also in my local machine.

it all over the place , how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably fix it by changing your default culture, or by forcing the use of a specific culture in the conversion calls <sup>(a)</sup>.

Our wonderful, yet somehow slightly disturbing European cousins have gotten the decimal point and comma mixed up at some point in the past, so that thirty-five-thousand-and-seven-point-two-five is written as:

```
35.007,25
```

So what's almost certainly happening is that your culture settings are throwing away the thousands separator (regardless of where they are) so that "2.5" *is* 25. This means that a number like two-and-half-thousand (`2,500`) would almost certainly become two-and-a-half.

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: In fact, you probably *shouldn't* force a specific culture in the conversion call, since the whole point of cultures is to adapt to people's needs. The Europeans thinks little enough of US bods already without giving them *more* reasons :-) What you're seeing is *exactly* what's supposed to be happening.

If you need a specific culture, configure your machine that way, and let your code use the default.

Comment: i changed manualy the culture on master page_load. to fix it i just change the culture when i start the function and get it back on last row of the function. Thanks you realy all help me get some new information

Answer (score 4):

What culture are you currently on? This should do the work:

```
decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal("2.5", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Also, for the comma showing:

```
string s = a.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: i have millions line of code to do that , there is another solution for this strange behavior?

Comment: You can set current culture in Web.config or App.config for the entire application.

Comment: iv done that , but there isnt any change its still has this comma in the grid and ignore the point when insert

Comment: its acttuly show comma instead of point 200,00 instead of 200.00

Comment: You're not doing it right. I don't know what else to say... this way it should work.

Comment: i set it this way:<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="en-US"/>

Comment: Try this: <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>